# Test if string ONLY contains given characters

Tags: python, string

What's the easiest way to check if a string only contains certain specified characters in Python? (Without using RegEx or anything, of course)

Specifically, I have a list of stings, and I want to filter out all of them except the words that are ONLY made up of ANY of the letters in another string. For example, filtering `['aba', 'acba', 'caz']` though `'abc'` should give `['aba', 'acba']`. (`z` not in `abc`)

Just like only keeping the items that can be made using the given letters.

Comment: you want to return 'acb' or 'acba'?

Comment: And what did you try to achieve it? Given the condition of no RegEx it looks very like a homework assignment.

Comment: what's wrong with regex ? that would be a quite trivial line...

Comment: @Joseph What do you mean?  The second item in the list is `'acba'` and in the expected output it is reduced to just `'acb'`?

Comment: Yes, I want it to return `acd` or `acba`. And no, this isn't actually homework, I'm writing a program that counts how many English words that can be made from constrained characters. But yes, I am a noob.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the discrepancy in your example is a typo, then this should work:

```
my_list = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
result = [s for s in my_list if not s.strip('abc')]
```

results in `['aba', 'acba']`.  [string.strip(characters)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will return an empty string if the string to be stripped contains nothing but characters in the input.  Order of the characters should not matter.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
>>> l = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
>>> s = set('abc')
>>> [item for item in l if not set(item).difference(s)]
['aba', 'acba']
```

Comment: @Bakuriu +1 Yup - where you've got a set already, use an appropriate method on that instead of converting another item to set and providing it the existing set :)

Comment: Uhm. It just occurred to me that `symmetric_difference` wont do. Because it matches if and only if `item` contains *exactly* the same elements of `s`(`set('abc').symmetric_difference('aba') -> {'c'}`). While we want `item` to be a `subset` of the elements, so `s.issuperset(item)` should do. :s

Comment: @Bakuriu your comment about `frozenset` was correct, tested and seen that `frozenset` is slower here. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I believe CPython has mostly the same implementation for `set` and `frozenset`s(e.g. there are common functions to create a new `set`, update it etc see the `Objects/setobject.c` file in the sources). `frozenset`s simply does not provide the methods that have side-effects. I removed that comment since the rest was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you only want the strings in your list which have only the characters in your search string, you can easily perform

```
>>> hay = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
>>> needle = set('abc')
>>> [h for h in hay if not set(h) - needle]
['aba', 'acba']
```

If you wan't to avoid sets, you can also do the same using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). In this case, you are removing all characters which are in your search string.

```
>>> needle = 'abc'
>>> [h for h in hay if not h.translate(None,needle)]
['aba', 'acba']
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
strings = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
given = "abc"
filter(lambda string: all(char in given for char in string), strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat ambiguous about re-using letters from the base string. Or if there should or should not be repeats, or missing letters allowed. This solution addresses that with a function including a `reuse` parameter:

```
from collections import Counter

def anagram_filter(data, base, reuse=True):
    if reuse: # all characters in objects in data are in base, count ignored
        base = set(base)
        return [d for d in data if not set(d).difference(base)]
    r = []
    cb = Counter(base)
    for d in data:
        for k, v in Counter(d).iteritems():
            if (k not in cb.keys()) or (v > cb[k]):
                break
        else:
            r.append(d)
    return r
```

Usage:

```
>>> anagram_filter(['aba', 'acba', 'caz'], 'abc')
['aba', 'acba']
>>> anagram_filter(['aba', 'acba', 'caz'], 'abc', False)
[]
>>> anagram_filter(['aba', 'cba', 'caz'], 'abc', False)
['cba']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code:

```
a = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
needle = 'abc'

def onlyNeedle(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in needle:
            return False

    return True

a = filter(onlyNeedle, a)

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your reluctance for regexp is not really an issue :

```
strings = ['aba', 'acba', 'caz']
given = "abc"
filter(lambda value: re.match("^[" + given + "]$", value), strings)
```

Comment: `re.escape(given)` would be safer.

Comment: @Paco : the `of course` part could indicate a prejudice of inherent complexity. I think this prejudice should be corrected. Hence my assumption. I could be wrong, of course, but I try to show that `RegEx or anything` are simple and friendly.